# Require Check-Out YES causing issue while updating , permissions for an item in EventReceiver

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, item-level-permissions

I am having the below settings in my doc library - `versioning settings` --> 
  `require check out` --> `YES` .
For this document library I  am writing an item level event receiver like - itemadded and itemupdated as well.
But somehow the item is not getting updated after performing some operations - like item level permissions, update another field in the same doc lib etc.

What are the code changes I need to do / add/update inside my runwitheleveatedprivieges codeblock , such that I get the correct results- ILP applied, updated field value.

Below is my  current code within `itemadded()`

```
 itemadded()
  {
 //// runwithelevatedprivileges
 //...foreach loop   
  try
  {
    GrantPermissionsTopLevelGroups
    (singleProjDocLibItem, pCurrentList, pCurrentWeb);
  }
  catch { }
  if (singleProjDocLibItem.File.Level != SPFileLevel.Checkout)
    {
      singleProjDocLibItem.File.CheckOut();
    }
     singleProjDocLibItem.SystemUpdate(false);
     singleProjDocLibItem.File.CheckIn("System_Checkedin");
     singleProjDocLibItem.File.Publish("System_Published");
```

Comment: Why do you need to check-out and check-in if you use the SystemUpdate method? As far as I can remember, this method allows you to update items while bypassing the checkout mechanism.

Comment: what will happen, if the doc lib item is already in check-out status? my update the another field or applying the permission may fail .

Comment: Fair pont. If the file is already checked out, then you have two options: either undo the check-out or check in on behalf of the user. Either of these options should be executed before the SystemUpdate method.